# ASP .Net MVC 2013

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

In Visual Studio I create an `ASP .NET Web Application` project with `MVC` template . Do not write any code yet, surprisingly after pressing F5 to compile and run the project, I can create an account, login with the created account.
My questions:

1. where is the code that handles the Creating account?
2. Where is my created account stored?
3. where is the code that handles the Login?
4. Is there some thing like a cookie variable that contains my account after successfully login?

Answer (score 0):

1. In the `AccountController`
2. Most likely it is using `localdb` - check the `AppData` folder of the solution
3. See 1.
4. Yes